# Sharing a video clip on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-windows

I published one video file on Ubuntu One. Sent the URL to a friend, but he is unable to download it. Firefox simply wants to play the file (and that is an impossibly slow process). How can one make a video file downloadable?

Comment: I am suffering from the same problem so I filled a bug about it, let'S see what happens. https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider/+bug/1132240

Answer (score 1):

That depends on a setting in Firefox. You can configure Firefox to automatically open, save or ask what to do for various type of files:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Applications Tab
```

Tell your friend to right click the download link, and select "Save link as...", instead of left clicking.

Comment: The "Save link as" option only works if the user is clicking the link from within firefox. A better option might be to tell the person to open a terminal and run "wget $url" if the user is on Ubuntu. If on Windows or OSX, some other options are available. Also, you could just wait for Firefox to start loading the video, and simply hit Ctrl+S to save the file.

Comment: ...and how do you know the OPs friend even has a terminal? I thought it best to provide a simple solution with the tools at hand in this particular case.

Comment: I don't know. Which is why I listed multiple options for how to do it, and not simply the terminal option.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest use **jdownloader** to download it. Simple paste it on **Link Grabber** and choose **Deep decryption** for video if needed.